# Can you identify a box that says LEGO Extra Parts no. 058?

Tags: set-identification

I got a box that says LEGO Extra Parts. Think number is #058 any help?

[image] [image]

Answer (score 5):

It's a Samsonite supplemental pack

[058-1: Small wheels](http://brickset.com/sets/058-1/Small-wheels)